# Как создать SQL запрос без конструктора в Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, веб-программирование, laravel

Мне не нужно делать запрос вида SELECT или INSERT, я понимаю, что конструктором это сделать проще и лучше. Однако мне необходимо запустить процедуру находящеюся на MsSQL Server. Можно ли это осуществить конструктором? Если нет, то как можно по холопски руками прописать запрос в Laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иные запросы к БД

Используйте метод `statement` фасада `DB`:

```
DB::statement('drop table users');
```